# Bash script to fill forms on an opened website

Tags: bash, firefox, rhel

I'm struggling with this issue for a long time, and haven't found any 'elegant' way to achieve my goal. The idea is quite simple:

*After loading a webpage in Firefox browser I want to be able to fill the available textboxes with a bash script, and leave it for further editing.*

1. **Curl** and **wget** are a 'no-go' as both of them fill forms and send data directly to a specified website.
2. I've tried **xdotool** to go through all of the forms, but after filling every single one of the textboxes there is a slight time delay, that varies, before I'm able to jump to the next one. As you can imagine it is far more efficient for me to monitor for the right moment and fill the whole page by hand, rather than setting the maximum (observed) time to wait for every 'jump'.

P.S. I'm aware of the available extensions for Firefox, but I'm not permitted to go this way with my project. The system (which is RHEL6) and browser are not to be modified for this task. External repositories, and all the guidance are more than welcome.